# rviz odometry is doubling angle?

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I'm having some problems visualizing odometry with rviz. The problem I am encountering is that rviz appears to be doubling the angle given by the odometry message published:

When the orientation.z of the odometry message is 0.00 (as viewed by rostopic echo odom), the arrow in rviz is aligned vertically with a gridline, as expected

When the orientation.z of the odometry message is 1.58, the arrow in rviz is anti-parallel to the 0.00 arrow from before (~180 degree rotation = ~3.14 radians is approx. 2 * 1.58 radians)

When the arrow on rviz is perpendicular to the initial 0.00 arrow, the orientation.z reads about .707 radians = ~40 degrees.

I'm not too sure if this is a configuration error or not - I originally thought I had written my odometry publisher incorrectly until I started echoing the topic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Relevant Code:**

```
                //since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from yaw
                geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(
                                bot->m_odometry_yaw);

                //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
                geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
                odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
                odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
                odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

                odom_trans.transform.translation.x = bot->m_odometry_x;
                odom_trans.transform.translation.y = bot->m_odometry_y;
                odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
                odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

                //send the transform
                odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

                //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
                nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
                odom.header.stamp = current_time;
                odom.header.frame_id = "odom";

                //set the position
                odom.pose.pose.position.x = bot->m_odometry_x;
                odom.pose.pose.position.y = bot->m_odometry_y;
                odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
                odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

                //set the velocity
                odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
                odom.twist.twist.linear.x = bot->m_velocity_x;
                odom.twist.twist.linear.y = bot->m_velocity_y;
                odom.twist.twist.angular.z = bot->m_velocity_yaw;

                //publish the message
                odom_pub.publish(odom);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9400/rviz-odometry-is-doubling-angle?/) by [rbtying](https://answers.ros.org/users/285/rbtying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2011-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you may be confusing your datatypes.

RVIZ takes in a pose with (x,y,z) position and (x,y,z,w) orientation.  The orientation is represented by a quaternion.  For a quick refresher on quaternions, check out the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) page.

Probably what is happening is that you are incorrectly publishing your quaternions.

If you have a given set of rotations, in roll/pitch/yaw, you can convert these to a quaternion using the tf::transformations::quaternion_from_euler function.  By default it takes the euler angles in sxyz format (roll, pitch, then yaw).

For a bit of example code (in Python):

```
quat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,theta)
### Insert math into Odom msg so it can be published
odom_msg = Odometry()
odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.x = quat[0]
odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.y = quat[1]
odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.z = quat[2]
odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.w = quat[3]
```

This is for a differential drive robot, where there is no roll and pitch, and the kinematics are calculated shortly before this snippet of code.

So as an example:

```
 >>> tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,0)
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
 >>> tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,math.pi/2)
 array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.70710678])
 >>> tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,2*math.pi)
 array([ -0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.22460635e-16, -1.00000000e+00])
```

So, just keep in mind that all parts of the quaternion (x,y,z,w) have to be filled out, not just orientation.z.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-03-13**:
converted comment to answer (ran out of space)

**Comment by [rbtying](https://answers.ros.org/users/285/rbtying/) on 2011-03-13**:
I added the relevant code (C++) to the question - am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your code looks fine. The problem here is your interpretation of the "orientation" -- which is in fact a quaternion, not euler angles. Therefore, orientation.z is not the rotation about the z axis, but rather a component of the quaternion. For instance, using the tf.transformations module in python, we can see that when your marker is perpendicular (euler rotation about z of 1.57 radians), we have:

> > quaternion_from_euler(0,0,1.57) = array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70682518,  0.70738827])

Quaternion components are labeled (x,y,z,w), so the quaternion's "z" component will be 0.707 as you saw.

If you run the following (while your node is publishing tf messages):

> > rosrun tf tf_echo odom base_link

You can see the transformation in both euler angle and quaternion form.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbtying](https://answers.ros.org/users/285/rbtying/) on 2011-03-13**:
Thanks! That makes sense - I must have my odometry calibrated wrong then (short of rederiving the kinematics, I guess I'll just use a fudge factor of 2.0).  I've never really worked with quaternions before, so I was confused.